# Intellij Idea: Turn off asking for master password when accessing DB

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij keeps asking me for the master password every time I try to update, alter, or work with a database using it. I find this very annoying. Can it be turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the *Database* tool window (View > Tool Windows > Database). Then open the *Data Sources and Drivers* window by right-clicking on the name of the database and selecting the *Properties* option. Uncheck the *Auto sync* box in the *General* tab.